# Asp.net MVC Nhibernate : Can not modify more than one base table through a join view

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, database, nhibernate

I am working on `ASP.Net MVC` Web project with `NHibernate` and `MySQL`. Everything is ok but i am randomly getting error in the following flow.

```
NHibernate.ISession _Session = MvcApplication.SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();

using (ITransaction t = _Session.BeginTransaction())
  {
     SavedIDOfModel1 = (Int32)_Session.Save(Model1);
     //DAO will use same _Session to get data from DB
     Model2 oModel2 = DAO.GetModel2FromDB();     
    oModel2.Model1ID = SavedIDOfModel1;
    _Session.SaveOrUpdate(oModel2);
        t.Commit(); 
  }


//DAO will use same _Session to get data from DB

DAO.GetModel3FromDB();
DAO.AddHistoryInDB();
```

`AddHistoryInDB` is simply creating a new Model `HISTORY` and commiting it into DB. Model `HISTORY` needs only `CaseID` from previous `Model1`.

While saving `HISTORY`, some of the cases are not saving `history`. 
    this function will use same _session and new transaction to send data to DB

Just wanted to know is it the right approach i am using to insert data to DB in history function `DAO.AddHistoryInDB()` . ?

**EDIT :**

Following is the exception :

```
    Unable to add case history.

    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005):

 Can not modify more than one base table through a join view 

'easyslotdb.view_appointment' at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int64& insertedId) at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId, Int32& affectedRows, Int64& insertedId) at 

MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force) at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult() at 

MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at 

NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteNonQuery(IDbCommand cmd) at 

NHibernate.AdoNet.NonBatchingBatcher.AddToBatch(IExpectation expectation) at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Update(Object id, Object[] fields, Object[] oldFields, Object rowId, Boolean[] includeProperty, Int32 j, Object oldVersion, Object obj, SqlCommandInfo sql, ISessionImplementor session)
```

As per my understanding it happens when we update database View but i am not updating it in my case.. can any one help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NHibernate sessions keep track of their transaction and handle their disposing, no need to do `using` on their transaction. Do a "try work commit catch rollback" instead.

`SaveOrUpdate` call is an error. `Save` is for persisting a new entity, [`Update`](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/manipulatingdata.html#manipulatingdata-updating-detached) is for attaching an already persisted entity coming from another session into the current session, for allowing it to eventually applies its changes on a later `Flush`. It is far from being equivalent to the SQL `UPDATE`. This is nonsense to call it on an entity loaded from the same session and not previously evicted.

There is no method for asking to update a specific entity in DB in NHibernate (neither in Entity Framework). There is a global [`Flush`](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/manipulatingdata.html#manipulatingdata-updating-insession) which applies all changes in db (insert/update/delete; see [its logic here](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/manipulatingdata.html#manipulatingdata-flushing)). Committing a transaction does also trigger a flush.

So, remove your using, remove the call to `SaveOrUpdate`, commit your transaction or rollback it in case of exception (and call `throw;` to let the exception do its job).

As for your actual question, no idea. Without the code of `AddHistoryInDB` nor a detailed explanation of what is "saving history" in your case, I am quite clueless.

Side notes:

- Rather than casting the `Save` return value to your id type, you may read it directly on `Model1` after the `Save`.
- If you have mapped a `Model1` entity property on `Model2` corresponding to `Model1ID`, avoid having both. As long as proxyfying is not disabled, just keep the entity property and assign to it your entity for changing it. In the case you only have its id, `_Session.Load<Model1>(id)` would yield you a proxy without hitting the DB.

### Addressing comment questions:

Nothing wrong with first `Save`, I was pointing the `SaveOrUpdate`. (I was just giving an hint for avoiding the ID cast, but this `Save` must stay.)

On the commit subject, we do not need to ensure `Model1` exists before associating it on `Model2`. NHibernate handles that, it knows how to `Flush` all into DB in the right order. You lose the unit of work semantic with this `Commit`.

In a web context, it is more usual to have one transaction covering all your db impacts. You may issue intermediate flushes (for ensuring your view will be able to give you your intended data), but no need for `Commit`. Your current case should be a unit of work, as I currently see it. So it should be inside a single transaction.

About the view, I guess this a DB view. In that case, you are safer issuing an explicit `_Session.Flush()` before querying it. But it could be interesting you test what happen without it: NHibernate may issued it itself when you ask him querying your view, depending on how you have map it. (See [`Flush` documentation](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/manipulatingdata.html#manipulatingdata-flushing).)

Comment: Thanks Frederic for your nice and detailed explanation.

Just couple of things:

1. Model1 ID is auto generated in DB thats why i used Save to get that ID. as after saving Model1 i need this id for Model2.

2. I was using transaction.commit() just to make sure that Model1 is successfully committed before touching Model2 and also after that i need one view for which Model1 must be commited before using that view.

3. Regarding session...i am binding NHibernate session in begin request and then unbinding and disposing it in end request event in global.asax.

Comment: I have edited my answer for responding to your comment, and I have adjusted some points in my first answer too.